# MVC Post a request with model when table has checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I found some guide, found a working example, but when I try to build it on my own it just fails.
I trying to display a collection of items and of the left of each row there should be a checkbox. when hitting the button it should send the collection to the controller and I should be able to extract the selected items.
Here is a code sample I wrote and I have no idea why it does not work

the controller

```
public class PeopleController : Controller
{
    PeopleRepo repo = new PeopleRepo();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var controllerModel = new PeopleControllerModel();
        foreach (var item in repo.GetPeople())
        {
            controllerModel.SelectablePersons.Add(new SelectablePersonEditorViewModel { PersonModel = item });
        }

        return View(controllerModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upgrade(PeopleControllerModel model)
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

PeopleControllerModel

```
public class PeopleControllerModel
{
    public List<SelectablePersonEditorViewModel> SelectablePersons { get; set; }

    public PeopleControllerModel()
    {
        SelectablePersons = new List<SelectablePersonEditorViewModel>();
    }
}
```

SelectablePersonEditorViewModel

```
public class SelectablePersonEditorViewModel
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public Person PersonModel { get; set; }

    public int PersonId
    {
        get { return PersonModel.PersonId; }
    }
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return PersonModel.FirstName; }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return PersonModel.LastName; }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.PeopleControllerModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upgrade", "People", FormMethod.Post, new { encType = "multipart/form-data", name = "myform" }))
{
    <p>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Upgrade"/>
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Is Selected</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>

        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.SelectablePersons)

    </table>
}
```

and the SelectablePersonEditorViewModel

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.SelectablePersonEditorViewModel

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.IsSelected)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.LastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.PersonId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.PersonId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id= Model.PersonId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id= Model.PersonId })
    </td>
</tr>
```

With above code I get the result of:
Inside SelectablePersonEditorViewModel I get a null ref exception due to PersonModel being null.
In another sample I tried I got in the controller when I reached the Upgrade method, the model method parameter was always empty (not null, simply a new instance).

I`d love to understand what is going on here and what am I missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You view model only has proprieties for `Person` which are getter, and the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot **set** the values. Change the view model to

```
public class SelectablePersonEditorViewModel
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and in the GET method, set the value of each property.

```
var model = new PeopleControllerModel()
{
    SelectablePersons = repo.GetPeople().Select(x => new SelectablePersonEditorViewModel()
    {
        PersonId = x.PersonId,
        FirstName = x.FirstName,
        LastName = x.LastName
    })
};
return View(model);
```

Comment: If I understand correctly how it work, it takes the rows from the request sent and builds the model from scratch, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And note that a view model should generally not contain properties which are data models. For example, while you could have used `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PersonModel.PersonId)`, if the data model had a `[Required]` attribute on say `FirstName`, `ModelState` would be invalid when you submit because you do not generate form controls for all properties of `mPersonModel` (and nor should you)